# Run 2 CSV file for 2 HTTP requests in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want run 2 different CSV files. Like I created 2 different HTTP Requests and 2 different CSV files, now I want to run both HTTP requests at the same time and data should from both CSV file.

Like:- 1 HTTP request should get data from 1 CSV file and 2 HTTP request should get data from 2 CSV file.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use different variables names in different CSV and use those variables in different HTTP requests

To execute in parallel, put your requests under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) plugin

> Parallel Controller is a Controller that allows execute child elements parallel